# After transferring file to another server I want to move source file to another folder is source server using lftp

Tags: linux, lftp

I was able to transfer files from host server to client server with `lftp`, but now as per requirement the files from host folder after transferring to client server should be moved to folder say "old" on host server itself. Maybe I need to use `lftp` with `--verbose`, can anyone help me how to use it.

My current command is

```
lftp -u username,password sftp://ipaddress -e "mirror --verbose --only-newer -c -R /Host/server/folders/subfolders/ /ClientServerFolder; quit"
```

Note: above command is from script which is placed in `crontab`.